# Amazon EC2 Instance Killing MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf

I believe my instance keeps killing MySQL every few days due to high CPU or memory usage.  The database is somewhat large (256 MB) I've tried the top command when connected to the instance, here's a snapshot:

```
Cpu(s): 64.3%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 34.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.3%st
Mem:   2051644k total,  2019380k used,    32264k free,     4196k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   284064k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
2573 apache    20   0  554m 145m  10m S 40.6  7.3   3:18.79 httpd
2572 apache    20   0  661m 151m  10m S 16.6  7.6   3:37.72 httpd
2481 mysql     20   0  861m 170m 4736 S  8.7  8.5   8:15.37 mysqld
```

I've seen CPU usage go as high as 80% just watching it for a few minutes.  What can I do to reduce the CPU or memory usage?  I increased the instance size to medium and it never crashes, however, that's quite expensive.  Thanks.

Comment: 1. ServerFault.  2. That happens when you run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the stats, you don't have a lot of free memory left. You may easily run into a situation where linux will start killing processes to free up memory. The system log will show messages related to oom-killer.

What can you do?

1. Enable Swap memory. Will allow you to exceed 2 GB, but can be very slow.
2. Tune mysql configuration to use less caching.
3. Disable any apache modules you are not using.
4. It looks like you may have a standard LAMP stack. If that is the case, configure php with fcgi instead of mod_php.

Comment: This is good advice. In addition I would add the option of running MySQL on a separate server so that it isn't competing for system resources with Apache.